# Why does this C program print the character 2?

Tags: c, printf, character, literals

```
int main(void)   
{  
    char c='012';  
    printf("%c",c);  
    return 0;  
}
```

Why is 2 getting printed?

Comment: First fix the warnings I am sure you are getting. Then come back.

Comment: `char c = '012'` is wrong here. Do you want to use a char (one number/letter) or a char array (multiple numbers/letters)?

Comment: @machine_1 The question was migrated. The comment is from CS SE

Comment: @eugene ahh, I did not know that comments are migrated also.

Comment: @MemAllox, the statement you point out is unlikely to be what is *intended*, but it is not wrong in the sense of being invalid.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, you are right! Wikipedia: _Multi-character constants (e.g. 'xy') are valid, although rarely useful — they let one store several characters in an integer (e.g. 4 ASCII characters can fit in a 32-bit integer, 8 in a 64-bit one). Since the order in which the characters are packed into one int is not specified, portable use of multi-character constants is difficult._ I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: @MemAllox: That article is misleading in the sense that it implies that all the characters are packaged somehow. That doesn't have to be the case: an implementation is free to ignore all the characters after the first one, for example.

Comment: @Bathsheba Ok, so I guess I'll keep my fingers off those, thanks :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'012'` is a multicharacter constant, which is an `int` type, but with an *implementation defined* value. (For the avoidance of doubt, `'0'` is an `int` type in C too.)

If `char` is `unsigned` then you'll get the least significant `CHAR_BIT` bits of that `int` as the final result. If `char` is `signed`, then then behaviour of the conversion of that `int` to the `char` will be implementation defined.

In your case, it appears that the constant value is `'0' * 256 * 256 + '1' * 256 + '2'`, and the conversion of this to `char` is effectively taking the result modulo 256.

Comment: I wasn't getting any warnings and ya only ane value can be stored in a character variable as such in a little endian machine, only the last byte is considered, am I right?

Comment: @Curious: Absolutely not.

Comment: @Curious, if you were not getting warnings then you should turn up the warning level or find a better compiler.  Any compiler worth using will warn about multi-character integer character constants.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally error which should be fixed. Look what comes out when I compile it with `-Wall` option:

```
gonczor@wiktor-papu:~/tmp$ gcc test.c -Wall -o test
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:5:12: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
     char c='012';
            ^~~~~
test.c:5:12: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
gonczor@wiktor-papu:~/tmp$ ./main 
31221344gonczor@wiktor-papu:~/tmp$ echo $?
1
```

The last line `echo $?` prints last command exit status. You can see it's 1, not zero.